# Efficient algorithm to optimize the result of queries with many fields?

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, data-mining

For a side project at work, I have a relatively small .CSV file (~150k rows) with data about historical loans, their rate of return, and the people who took them out. I need to find out what properties of a person taking out a loan correlate with the highest rate of return. Each row contains numeric data like the individual's credit score, monthly income, and the loan term, as well as qualitative data like the purpose for which he or she needs the loan. Each entry has 23 fields in total, and there are ~2-10 possible values per field.

My initial thought was to drop the .CSV into SQLite and then query every possible permutation of each field and pick out the highest rate of return from the results. At even .2ms/query, however, I realized that it would take ~400 years to complete the computation, which obviously doesn't work. Another solution that I considered was to select, say, the most profitable 10% of historical loans and find out what traits they most frequently shared. However, I suspect that this will just return the traits of very risky loans that "happened" to pay off -- not necessarily the most effective traits to select for when considering underwriting new loans.

The most reasonable solution I can think of would be to take the fields that can have a range of values (like income) and perform something like a binary search, e.g. split income into the top 50% and bottom 50%, select the one with the higher ROR, then split that into the top and bottom 50%, etc. I don't think this will work because a) it's not necessarily true that the income group with the highest ROR is contained within the half of the group with the highest ROR, and b) this recursive check would have to be redone for every permutation of the other values, still making it very expensive.

I imagine that problems like these are pretty common and that standard solutions exist, but I have no idea where I would start looking for one. What kind of solution is appropriate for this problem? Where can I go to read more about it?

My preference would be for a solution in Python, but if there's another tool that's better for the job I'm open to that. I apologize if this is off topic but I don't really know where else to ask it -- I left it sitting on CrossValidated for a week and a half without an answer before deleting it and reposting here.

Comment: I suggest you research "data mining".

Comment: Do you have any more specific recommendations? Specific libraries or languages that are suited to this task?

Comment: No, sorry, I've never actually done any of this kind of work myself. I just know that this is what you're describing, so if you google it and study how other people do it, that should get you going in the right direction. It's not a trivial project, it's something that entire companies have been created to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to hire a trained statistician as this type of task is nothing special. There are many techniques and tools you can use, my list is definitely not complete:

Tools:

- [R](http://www.r-project.org/)
- [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)
- [RapidMiner](http://rapid-i.com/content/view/181/)
- [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) (Python)
- [MADLib](http://madlib.net/)
- SAS (commercial)
- ....

Techniques:

- Linear Regression
- Logistic Regression (by encoding rate of return as 0/1 using arbitrary split)
- Decision Tree
- Neural Network
- Clustering
- ...

You really have to read some books if you should succeed. Or post anonymized dataset and maybe someone will help you more.

If you really would like to continue on your own, just try Weka or [Rattle](http://rattle.togaware.com/) (R), both have GUI one can understand easily and you can create your first model in minutes.

Rattle screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do a [Least Squares Fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) of the numerical values. Put all the numerical input-columns in a matrix (A, 150K×23), with each row as a row in the matrix. Put the output values in a vector (b, 150k long), in the same order as the corresponding rows in the matrix. Calculate:

> A' = A<sup>T</sup> A — This will result in a 23×23 matrix.
>   B' = A<sup>T</sup> b — This will result in a 23 long vector.
>   X = (A')<sup>-1</sup> B' — The result will be a 23 long vector of cofficients.

The resulting vector (X) will contain the magnitudes of each input variable.

The A' and B' matrices can be calculated iteratively:

> A'<sub>0</sub> = 0
>   A'<sub>n+1</sub> = A'<sub>n</sub> + x<sup>T</sup> x
>   B'<sub>0</sub> = 0
>   B'<sub>n+1</sub> = B'<sub>n</sub> + x<sup>T</sup> y

Where x is a single input-row, and y is the corresponding output value.

Here is an example in C#:

```cs
CsvReader data = new CsvReader("myfile.csv");

int[] inputColumns = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9 }; // The numerical input-columns
int outputColumn = 0;
int size = inputColumns.Length;

var A = new Matrix(size, size);
var b = new Vector(size);

foreach (var row in data)
{
    var inputs = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = double.Parse(row[inputColumns[i]]);
    }

    var output = double.Parse(row[outputColumn]);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        A[i,j] += inputs[i] * inputs[j];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        b[i] += inputs[i] * output;
    }
}

return (A.Inverse * b).ToList();
```

`CsvReader`, `Matrix` and `Vector` are not standard classes, so you will have to find some libraries that include those.